# Unable to return File[] location back as a string in Java

Tags: java

I have created some basic code that looks for a certain type of file within a folder via FilenameFilter. It does so successfully but I am unable to return the match found into a string. Wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
public static void renameFilesInConfFolder() {
        File dir = new File(directory+"\\conf");
        File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
          public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
          {
             return (name.contains("ods2-conf") && name.length()>13  && !name.contains("oracle"));
          }
        });
        String match = matches.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        return;
    }
```

EDIT: So I have removed VOID and updated it to a public String, with the return type for match, however the same issue occurs:

Updated code:

```
public static String renameFilesInConfFolder() {
        File dir = new File(directory+"\\conf");
        File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
          public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
          {
             return (name.contains("ods2-conf") && name.length()>13  && !name.contains("oracle"));
          }
        });
        String match = matches.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        return match;
    }
```

Matches currently is:

> [c:\location\newfile.txt]

when i do `matches.toString()` match ends up being:

> Ljava.io.File;@42906563

Comment: the return type of method `renameFilesInConfFolder` is `void`

Comment: and once you fix that put `return match;` at the end

Comment: create the return type of your method as `String` and return statement should be `return match`

Comment: Hi, I have updated my comment. It unfortunately doesnt return the actual text though, rather just a bunch of jibberish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` is an array, calling `toString` on an array will give you incorrect representation. You need to iterate over the array to get the string value

```
String match ="";

for(File f: files){
   if(!match.isEmpty()) match+=",";
   match+=f.toString();
}
return match;
```

Comment: May be worth adding some kind of delimiter between the files, no?

Comment: yep, missed it earlier.

Comment: Never call `+=` on a String in a loop;  it creates a new String object with each iteration.  Use StringBuilder instead.  Even better, your entire block of code can be replaced with `Arrays.toString(files)` or `Arrays.stream(files).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Arrays.toString(...)`. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm). The problem is you're calling `.toString()` on an array, and array doesn't override the `toString()` method in the way you expect it does, so it's just printing some location in memory.

Change this line:

```
String match = matches.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

to this:

```
String match = Arrays.toString(matches).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Comment: Simpler answer, and should work in current scenario. I usually avoid it as it give null value as "null".